# The logic behind any() and if-statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a code trying to realize a part of that:

I have matrix `A` as:

```
0.241 0.095 0.695
0.002 0.774 0.590
0.991 0.406 0.997
0.435 0.217 0.087
0.729 0.898 0.343
```

I dont understand the logic behind this statement:

```
if ((any(0.250 <= A[ ,3] & A[ ,3] <= 0.375)) == FALSE) {
   print("Done")
}
```

`A[ ,3]` gives `0.695 0.590 0.997 0.087 0.343`

`0.250 <= A[ ,3]` gives `TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE`

`A[ ,3] <= 0.375` gives `FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE`

and the if statement returns nothing, however, when I change `0.250` to `0.4`:

`0.4 <= A[ ,3]` gives `TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE`

`A[ ,3] <= 0.375` gives `FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE`

This time the if statement print `"Done"`

is that about the number of `FALSE` or `TRUE`?

Comment: Check what `0.250 <= A[ ,3] & A[ ,3] <= 0.375` gives you. `any` tests if any of the values it has been passed is a logical `TRUE`. If that's the case it returns `TRUE` else it returns `FALSE`. The `if` condition prints `"Done"` if no value fulfills both conditions.

Comment: It gives `FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE`. I understood that. Thank you very much

Comment: Don't test explicitly for `TRUE` or `FALSE`, instead negate `!any(etc)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, `0.250 <= A[ ,3] & A[ ,3] <= 0.375` returns `FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE`, the logical `&` returning `TRUE` only when both the statements are `TRUE`. The `any()` function then checks if any of the values passed to it evaluate to `TRUE`. Thus, it returns `TRUE` in this case, doesn't satisfy the conditon and doesn't enter the loop.

In the second case, `0.4 <= A[ ,3] & A[ ,3] <= 0.375` returns `FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE` so `any()` function returns `FALSE` and satisfies the condition to enter the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is very ugly logic, equivalent and simpler code `if (all(A[ ,3] < 0.250 | A[ ,3] > 0.375))`.

Comment: This answer is wrong, the negation of a conjunction is a disjunction. And the negation of `<=` is `>`. The condition should be `all(A[ ,3] < 0.250 | A[ ,3] > 0.375)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas You are right, I did not see that the numbers shifted place in the comparison, first on the left and then on the right side.